# How to print to a Bluetooth printer with ReactJS web app from phone

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, printing, bluetooth

I'm trying to implement print to a Bixolon Bluetooth POS printer with our ReactJS web app. I've implemented the print functionality with [react-to-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print) - which works fine on PC, as the Bluetooth printer is detected with proper drivers installed. The problem is that the phone does not recognise this printer as printer when connected.

I can think of two solutions - but they might not be easy to implement. I could write an Java app which would listen to request of my React app and would trigger the print, or I could rewrite the project to React-Native and use [react-native-bluetooch-escpos-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer)
 (which would take way too much work as the project is already big).

I've also found [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) which, I think, should allow me to use [react-native-bluetooch-escpos-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer)
.

What would be the optimal solution here?